# Move character with device rotation(android-UE4)

Tags: android, unreal-engine4

I am trying to make a game for android and make the character move with mobile rotation.
For example, if the user rotates mobile clockwise character move right and otherwise move left.
have can I access to a rotation of device?
Any help will be appreciated.
(using ue4.25 & blueprint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to look at this post :

https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/android-development/1690-accelerometer-gyroscope-tilt

I believe what you need is a node to retreive the tilt of the device (post linked contains links to documentation about that)

Comment: I will try it. Thank you a lot :).

Comment: A pleasure to help